# How to avoid displaying old data in DataGrid (populated using EntityFramework instance) when the project is rebuilt?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, sql-server-2019-express

I am being displayed old data when I run the WPF app. I have created two dbcontexts on two different pages. When I rebuild the solution, I get the old data. I have also selected the value of "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer." It does not display old data when the app is **run**.

*Let me know if anything related to the code is needed.*

Comment: What do you mean by "I rebuild the solution, I get the old data" and "does not display old data when the app is run"? Rebuilding solution does not change data in database? Where do you "run" your app?

Comment: @Bill Joeden pls add your code and more details.